# Unglobalising a namespaced class without editing the header

Tags: c++, namespaces, protocol-buffers

Google provide a protobuf template for messages they send from their Ad Exchange network. (Available freely [here](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/downloads/realtime-bidding-proto.txt)) I use `protoc` to turn this template into C++ code (autogenerated). I have a problem where one of the classes' names clashes with one defined by me, something like

```
#include "realtime-bidding.pb.h"

// g++ complains that BidRequest is ambiguous.
void BidRequest::FromGoogle(const std::string& protobuf)
{
    // This what I want to write:
    // Google::BidRequest r;
    // r.ParseFromString(protobuf);
    if (r.has_field())
    {
        this->field = r.field();
    }
}
```

I am unable to do this without editing the files auto-generated by `protoc` (not good as we'll have to do this each time the `.proto` file is changed), and I cannot figure out a way to do this through the use of `namespaces`.

What the real issue is that Google insist that some of the classes are in the global namespace, e.g.

```
// from realtime-bidding.pb.h
class Bidrequest_Mobile : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
    inline ::BidRequest_Mobile_DeviceOsVersion* mutable_os_version();`.
           ^^
}
```

so I cannot do something like

```
namespace Google {
#include "realtime-bidding.pb.h"
}
```

as it'll stop the auto-generated code from compiling.

Namespacing my code would mean far too many changes to a very, very large codebase, although it is probably the correct solution. However, I am where I am.

Is there any trick to get this all to work without editing autogenerated files?
Is there a reason why some of the classes are put into the global namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `package` in your .proto files.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#packages

Comment: Seems to be the best solution. However the .proto file is provided by Google so we'll have to remember to add the package each time it's changed. It'd be nice if the protoc command allowed you to specify a package